# Error handling with pxssh and python logging not logging the errors

Tags: python, logging

Ok, I'm working on getting any timeouts, connection failures, password denied...to log with logging. I had the warnings for `TIMEOUT` in my console, but nothing else is working and I'm getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` now. I know I'm close to cracking this, but spinning my wheels now. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**CODE**

```
import pexpect
import pxssh
import getpass
import sys
import os
import re
import traceback
from pyparsing import *
import logging

lgr = logging.getLogger('error_config')
lgr.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ec = logging.FileHandler('error_config.log')
ec.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

frmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ec.setFormatter(frmt)

lgr.addHandler(ec)


def die(s, errstr):
    logging.warning(errstr)
    logging.warning(s.before, s.after)
    s.terminate()
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=60, maxread=2000000)
    s.force_password = True
    hostname = raw_input('Hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('Username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.PROMPT = 'SSH> '
    s.login(hostname, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False)
    logging.info("test")
    logging.info("Logged in")

    i = s.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'Permission denied', pexpect.EOF])
    if i == 0:
        die(s, 'Timed out. SSH log:')
    elif i == 1:
        die(s, 'Incorrect password. SSH log:')
    elif i == 2:
        print s.before
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging/__init__.py", line 731, in emit
  File "logging/__init__.py", line 617, in format
  File "logging/__init__.py", line 405, in format
  File "logging/__init__.py", line 276, in getMessage
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error_config.py", line 91, in ?
    main()
  File "error_config.py", line 43, in main
    die(s, 'Time out. SSH log:')
  File "error_config.py", line 27, in die
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: on what line you get this error? can you add the stack trace?

Comment: @Elisha sure, let me edit this now with the stack trace. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I think I already found the problem, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

`logging.WARNING` is `int` so you can't do:

```
logging.WARNING(errstr)
logging.WARNING(s.before, s.after)
```

I think you meant to use `logging.warning` instead:

```
logging.warning(errstr)
logging.warning(s.before, s.after)
```

after your edit, it seems like `exit` is overriden, probably by `from pyparsing import *`.

try to add `import sys` and use `sys.exit` intead of `exit`

Comment: Hmm, now I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: sorry my stack trace with your changes are in the edit above. Thanks!